# how to push notification to different clients(android and c# application) from a single amazon sns web service

Tags: c#, android, amazon-web-services

I need to implement a cloud service with push notification. The cloud service should be able to communicate with android device as well as windows applications(c++, c#). Please suggest your ideas how to achieve my requirement
which Amazon web service I have to use to meet my requirement?
Please help me to resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.